# In a Wikipedia article am I able to insert information licensed with CC BY even though they use a CC BY-SA license?

Tags: creative-commons, license-compatibility, cc-by, cc-by-sa

**Background:**

While writing an article on Wikipedia I needed to include text that is licensed under a CC-BY license. After a bit of digging I found that Wikipedia uses a CC BY-SA license.

**Question:**

Despite Wikipedia using a CC-BY-SA license, will I run into problems if I include CC-BY licensed text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can merge information from CC-BY sources into a CC-BY-SA work (but not the other way). That is because CC-BY-SA still includes all conditions of CC-BY.

Note, as suggested by Martijn in the comments: It is still important to correctly attribute the changes to their respective author (as bot CC-BY and CC-BY-SA demand). Also Wikipedia can have it's own guidelines for using tests from different sources, that extend over what the license demands.

Comment: Note though that attribution must be retained, so for Wikipedia, you should use the edit summary to provide attribution as required by the author (usually with a link to the source)

Comment: You're right, I edit that into my answer.